# Compiling in checked and unckecked context

Tags: c#

What is the value of `j`?

```
Int32 i = Int32.MinValue;
Int32 j = -i;
```

Compiling in checked context will throw an exception.
In unchecked we obtain value `Int32.MinValue`.

But why so?

Comment: But why not? ...  Consult a tutorial on bitwise encoding and 2-s complement.

Comment: Because `Int32` doesn't have enough bits for holding `-Int32.MinValue`

Comment: I understand that work so iconic types and it is correct. I just want to understand this on a deeper level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is min and max Int32 values:

```
                   Dec         Bin (first bit is a sign bit)
Int32.MinValue  -2147483648  10000000000000000000000000000000
Int32.MaxValue   2147483647  01111111111111111111111111111111
```

When you are trying to get `-(-2147483648)` with explicit overflow checking you get exception in this case, because `2147483648` is bigger than max allowed value for int type.

Then why you are getting MinValue when overflow is allowed? Because when Int32.MinValue is negated you have `2147483648` which has binary representation `10000000000000000000000000000000` but with signed integer first bit is a sign bit, so you get exactly Int32.Min value.

So, the problem here is treating first bit as number sign. If you would assign result of negated Int32.Min value to unsigned integer, you would get `2147483648` value, as expected:

```
Int32 i = Int32.MinValue;
UInt32 j = (UInt32)-i; // it has 32 bits and does not treat first bit as sign
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of integer overflow. In a checked context, the integer overflow will be detected and converted to an exception, because the language designers decided so.

To explain integer overflow, you can do the calculation in binary by hand. To calculate -X, take X in binary, change all the 1's to 0's and 0's to 1's, then add 1 (the number 1, not a 1 bit).

```
Example:     5 = 00000000000000000000000000000101
flip all bits:   11111111111111111111111111111010
add one:         11111111111111111111111111111011 which is -5

Int32.MinValue = 10000000000000000000000000000000
flip all bits:   01111111111111111111111111111111
add one:         10000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you take Int32.MinValue and negate it, it doesn't change. -Int32.MinValue can't fit in an int - if you do -(Int64)Int32.MinValue it will work as expected.